# Can you grep a file using a regular expression and only output the matching part of a line?

Tags: unix, shell, grep

I have a log file which contains a number of error lines, such as:

```
Failed to add email@test.com to database
```

I can filter these lines with a single grep call:

```
grep -E 'Failed to add (.*) to database'
```

This works fine, but what I'd really like to do is have grep (or another Unix command I pass the output into) only output the email address part of the matched line.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use sed:

```
grep -E 'Failed to add (.*) to database'| sed 's/'Failed to add \(.*\) to database'/\1'
```

Comment: @rogerdpack: It looks like you're right.  `-o` would return the set of strings 'Failed to add *some@addre.ss* to database', while the OP only wants *some@addre.ss*.

Comment: My problem even with `grep -o` being useful but not specifically for regex matched groups is that I needed `grep` over `sed` to match newline characters in multiline mode.  Instead of finding something that supported `s/.../.../m` I used `grep -z`.  Paired that with another `grep -oz` and my pattern cooperating to allow me to only select a portion of the content I want with those line types being different enough from each other, I had my solution!  Thinking on this, especially without trying to match the entire line, this could be an area for a patch..

Answer (score 15):

`sed` is fine without grep:

```
sed -n 's/Failed to add \(.*\) to database/\1/p' filename
```

Comment: Surely he could of used awk also !!

Answer (score 8):

You can also just pipe grep to itself :)

```
grep -E 'Failed to add (.*) to database' | grep -Eo "[^ ]+@[^ ]+"
```

Or, if "lines in interest" are the only ones with emails, just use the last grep command without the first one.

Answer (score 5):

Recent versions of GNU grep have a `-o` option which does exactly what you want. (`-o` is for `--only-matching`).

Comment: using `-o` would display the part matched to regex insted of the whole line in which the match was found. but @Olly wanted only the first subgroup (the e-mail address, w/o the surrounding text).

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
grep -x -e '(?<=Failed to add ).+?(?= to database)'
```

It uses a positive look-ahead assertion, followed by the match for the email address, followed by a postivie look-behind assertion. This insures that it matches the entire line, but only actually consumes (and thus returns) the email address part.

The `-x` option specifies that grep should match lines rather than the whole text.

Comment: Note that you should add `-P` flag for grep to support look-ahead and look-behind. And at least look-behind expression should have fixed length - no `.*` or whatever in it.

Answer (score 1):

or python:

```
cat file | python -c "import re, sys; print '\r\n'.join(re.findall('add (.*?) to', sys.stdin.read()))"
```

Answer (score 1):

`-r` option for `sed` allows regexps without backslashes

```
sed -n -r 's/Failed to add (.*) to database/\1/p' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use grep and output only matching part of line

```
grep -E -o 'Failed to add (.*) to database'
```

Then maybe if you want to write it to a file

```
cat yourlogfile | grep -E -o 'Failed to add (.*) to database' >> outputfile
```

So as of grep utility `-o` is going to  `-o, --only-matching       show only nonempty parts of lines that match'`.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use grep, it would be more appropiate to use egrep;

```
About egrep

Search a file for a pattern using full regular expressions.
```

grep will not always have as complete of functionality for regex.

Comment: He already uses egrep since he uses -E. NOthing to do with the problem which is controlling output.

Comment: What are you talking about?  If you see the "tag", he's asking about *UNIX* grep, which is not (as your answer suggest's) GNU-Everywhere, refer to http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Grep/grep_reference.shtml for some review of the various grep version's on UNIX (NOT GNU GREP), what you will see in black and white, "Limited regex - grep", "Extended regex - egrep".  So _REGARDLESS_ of the fact that GNU grep may be (is) better, it's not going to be something you can *always* count on, being deployed and being available for all your scripts.  My entire point is that you can not count on grep"basic"

Comment: I fail to see the point. The OP said nothing about the OS he uses except "Unix". So it can be an Unix where GNU grep is the default (Debian, for instance) or an Unix where GNU grep could be installed immediately with one command (NetBSD with pkg_add textproc/grep)